# Zend Form populate word with à (final) not displayed in form

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding, populate

I have this problem very crazy. I have setted the page HTML, the envioremnt and the DB with UTF-8 and all work fine.
The problem is with the word (or a string) that is with "à" final ex: autorità, papà and so on because when populate the form the input is empty. Write and read from database is ok because I have print it before populate and print in the page.
With other special char work ok (è, ì, ò etc..), only with à final the field is empty. I have tried too with "autorità some" and work but if the string is with à final no.

Anyone can help me in this strange problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the problem. to solve it I used utf8_encode:

```
$this->escape(utf8_encode($your_value));
```

I hope it will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem was a filter Trim applied to my field. I have delete it and change way... Thanks